# No response from firebase realtime database after i signed out and then logged in. There is no error and all database references are correct

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am developing and android application in which I am using firebase realtime database and firebase authentication. It was working fine till now. But when I signing out and again logging in, Authentication is successful but realtime database is not responding. When I installed the same apk file in another phone it works and after signing out same problem.
I found a solution that changing network and it works for sometime and again problem occurred.

```
package com.*****.****;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.Objects;


public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button loginButton;
    private ImageView navButton;
    private TextView signUpButton, forgotButton;
    private EditText emailField, passwordField;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference mLoginRef;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private NavigationView navigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        init();


        navButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawerLayout, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();
                switch (id) {
                    case R.id.login_nav_lang:
                        break;
                    case R.id.login_nav_display:
                        break;
                    case R.id.login_nav_invite_buddy:
                        startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, BDTSignUp.class));
                        break;
                    case R.id.login_nav_franchise:

                    case R.id.login_nav_career:

                    case R.id.login_nav_privacy_policy:

                    case R.id.login_nav_about:

                    case R.id.login_nav_contact:

                    default:
                        return true;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });

        signUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, SignUpIntro.class));
                finish();
            }
        });

        forgotButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //TODO Fill this slot
            }
        });

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                validateFields();
            }
        });
    }

    private void validateFields() {
        String email = emailField.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = passwordField.getText().toString().trim();

        if (email.equals("")) {
            emailField.setError("Email ID is Required");
            emailField.requestFocus();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (password.equals("")) {
            passwordField.setError("Password is Required");
            passwordField.requestFocus();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            login(email, password);
        }


    }

    private void login(String email, String password) {
        try {
            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                String uid = Objects.requireNonNull(mAuth.getCurrentUser()).getUid();
                                getUserDetails(uid);
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(Login.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        }
                    });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
    
//
//
//This is where problem occours. At beggining it works fine and after logout, database is not responding.
//
// 
    private void getUserDetails(String uid) {
        mLoginRef.child(uid)
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.exists()) {
                            String name = snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                            //Here is where I face problem.
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }

    private void init() {
        navButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.login_nav_button);

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.login_main_activity);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.login_navigation_view);

        loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_login_button);

        signUpButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_signup_button);
        forgotButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_forgot_button);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.login_progress);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mLoginRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("login");
        mLoginRef.keepSynced(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the code so that others can help you.

Comment: I have posted the code. U can check it. I don't think it will help.